Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter] in java21 and spring boot version 3.2.4
I am using spring boot version 3.2.4 from 2.6 and java21 from java11. while deploying the project getting  Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter] error.
i have tried to deploy the app. but , am getting the error like
Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter].
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter]
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:257)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:88)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:70)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter]
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1234)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@30.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to instantiate AttributeConverter [com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter]
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AbstractPropertyHolder.buildExceptionFromInstantiationError(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:127)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AbstractPropertyHolder.resolveAttributeConverterDescriptor(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:102)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.makePropertyAndValue(PropertyBinder.java:265)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.makePropertyValueAndBind(PropertyBinder.java:297)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.createBasicBinder(PropertyBinder.java:1169)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bindBasic(PropertyBinder.java:1071)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.bindProperty(PropertyBinder.java:890)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.buildProperty(PropertyBinder.java:788)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.PropertyBinder.processElementAnnotations(PropertyBinder.java:709)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(EntityBinder.java:1041)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.handleIdentifier(EntityBinder.java:357)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindEntityClass(EntityBinder.java:237)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:423)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:256)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:279)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:322)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1432)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:366)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create AttributeConverter instance
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AbstractPropertyHolder.makeAttributeConverterDescriptor(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:145)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AbstractPropertyHolder.resolveAttributeConverterDescriptor(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:99)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Could not extract type argument from attribute converter class 'com.cl.data.model.converter.IntegerTypeConverter'
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.convert.internal.ConverterHelper.resolveConverterClassParamTypes(ConverterHelper.java:101)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.convert.internal.AbstractConverterDescriptor.<init>(AbstractConverterDescriptor.java:43)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.convert.internal.ClassBasedConverterDescriptor.<init>(ClassBasedConverterDescriptor.java:32)
    at deployment.dialers-api.war//org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.AbstractPropertyHolder.makeAttributeConverterDescriptor(AbstractPropertyHolder.java:141)
    ... 61 more


I would say mixing incompatible versions or not having updated your IntegerTypeConverter to the new JakartaEE API and just added a persistence-api dependency to make it compile (instead of actually fixing the error with the proper imports).
